# Error with create_list in tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am doing Austin Kabiru's informative api [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-one) but when I get to the point I want to run the todos requests spec, I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: let!(:todos) { create_list(:todo, 10) }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `create_list
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the configure Rspec block is not being executed in the `spec/rails_helper.rb` file. According to the tutorial, the block should start

```
RSpec.configuration do |config|
```

but in fact, to get it to work I needed to change it to

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
```